# Is there a GNOME extension which shows screen snapshots in the grid when switching workspaces?

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Since Ubuntu 18.04 switched from Unity I have to learn how to use GNOME and tailor it to suit me. I installed the "Workspace Grid" extension to arrange the workspaces in a grid, just like Unity used to have it.

Now I'm looking into how I can make individual workspaces in the grid show a snapshot of the screen. I want to see all the apps open in a workspace when the grid pops up as I switch from one to another with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd>. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can press <Super> key (or click "Activities") to get to Activities overview and then press <pg up>/<pg down> keys to navigate between workspaces and you'll get to see windows of running applications on each workspace.

Comment: thanks, I figured that out. But I want to go back using the workspace grid, like in Unity. I work with a lot of workspaces where each one has an app I need in it, and the way Unity was showing the grid helped me manage them really well.

Comment: looks like this is still an issue in the workspace grid extension, see https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid/issues/4